# PDF working in chrome but not in IE

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery.min.js,jquery-ui.js,jquery-ui.css JS for PDF display Viewer , its content coming and working properly in chrome but not in IE 9+ content is not coming?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. And finish the tour!

Answer (score 0):

i highly recommand you to use https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ to display pdf. Is this library who are on Chrome and Firefox to display PDF in new tab

Comment: i have to display PDF in IE my code is already running in chrome

Comment: i understand Neeraj, this attached library will do the work for all browser, but if you insist to use this one only on Internet explorer, you can add this condition on your code.

Comment: i found that in my code atob() and Uint8Array() is giving problem in IE ,any alternative of these method can you suggest me.

Comment: YOu have to install polyfill : 
 - Atob : https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js/
 - Uint8Array : https://github.com/substack/typedarray